# Can an event be dispatched to Activity after onDestroy?

Tags: android

Consider that activity is destroyed and onDestroy was fired. Can I be sure that no other messages will be dispatched into this activity handlers like onKeyDown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, no.

"OnDestroy

The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Seems to be so. My error was that I expected finish() to call onDestroy() immediatelly, but seems that some internal messages dispatching happens before onDestroy() is invoked. And I guess onKeyUp also could be called in the middle.